# htaccess use redirect string as part of destination url

Tags: .htaccess

I hope someone can help with htaccess. I have searched up and down the internet and couldn't figure it out.

Currently I was trying to use this:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <20231231
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^test1234$ https://example.com/assets/files/%{QUERY_STRING}.pdf [L]
```

When the visitor enters `https://example.com/test1234` htaccess should take `test1234` as a string and put it at the end of the url like this `https://examples.com/assets/files/test1234.pdf`

But I get only `https://example.com/assets/files/.pdf`

There must be something missing I'm over seeing. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a bit more about the different parts of a URL from the point of view of the rewriting engine. There is no query part in the requested URL, so you cannot somehow match or use it. Instead the string you are interested in is part of the *path* component of the URL. So you need to match that.

Take a look at this implementation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /assets/files/$1.pdf [END]
```

This rule probably needs to get adjusted for real life usage. You might want to combine it with conditions. I just want to point you into the right direction.

A variant of above approach would be to add a condition checking for the existence of the document first:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteCond /assets/files%1.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^ /assets/files/%1.pdf [END]
```

I really recommend that you start reading the documentation of the tool you are trying to use. As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html